# Best practice / Common patterns for Data centric application with jpa, hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

we are currently starting to implement a nee software which heavily uses database entities.
You can think of IT like a database Editor with some additional Business logic, validation,...
We use spring boot with jpa, hibernate and jsf as View technology.
One use case ist for example:
- search for an entity (show a list of matching results)
- open one entity for editing
- change or add some entity props
- save or cancel edit Mode
- back to list which Shows the updated entity

What will be a good pattern of handling the entities in that Case?
I mean in Terms of copying, binding and updating or reverting the entity and its Changes.

Will ist be a good Idea to create a clone of the entity WE want to edit and bind this clone to the ui? Then change this entity directly and persist/merge it on save or just throw it away in case of canceling.

Or should we use a more leighweight DTO which WE map from the original entity and bind this to the ui?

Last posibility is to perform inplace editing on the entity to Open. The changes will not be persisted before save.

WhatsApp about validation? is IT a good idea to define and use bean validation directly on the entity?

Thanks for all advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO it depends on your case, but you should consider:

1. Are you showing the same data in your views? If not, think about how to separate BO's and DTO's
2. Performance between frontend and backend. Is the performance a non functional requirement? I mean, if the performance critical you should only return data to be changed or to be viewed.
3. DTO is a pattern, it's useful sometimes, not always: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html

Other aspects:

1. Validations: in my opinion you should validate DTO fields in the binding phase, so the spring approach is Validator interface: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation 
   On this way, you can return errors as soon as possible to the view
2. You are talking about "cloning" objects, but if you mean about duplicate or develop more code I don't agree. You can choose tools like mapstruct, dozer or orika to avoid this.

I hope it helps.